# Getting deeply nested attribute values

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

I'm trying to get and change the value from the attribute value="1" from class="product-quantity"

```
<div class="product-list-content">
 <div class="product-items">
  <table class="product-items" data-list="291156" data-list- 
    mode="grouped">
    <tr class="product" data-product="11917" data-from-none="" data- 
      quantity="1" data-tr-location="Product List">
      <td class="product-quantity">
        <div>
            <label for="product-item-quantity-11917" class="sr- 
                only">Antall Gourmet Grovbrød</label>
            <input aria-live="assertive" id="product-item-quantity-11917" 
                data-action="set-quantity" value="1" maxlength="3" 
            ...
        </div>
      </td>

    ...

      <td class="product-info">
        <a href="/produkter/11917-brodverket-gourmet-grovbrod-oppskaret/" 
         class="modal-link">Gourmet Grovbrød</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

This works:

```
document.querySelector("#product-item-quantity-11917").value = "2"
```

but I don't want to hardcode every product-item-quantity, I want to find each and everyone dynamically, alongside the innerHTML of class="modal-link".

I've also tried this

```
var tables; 
tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
var table;
table = tables[1] //"product"-table
table.rows[x].getElementsByClassName("product-quantity") //let x be some 
//integer in the range of rows.
```

which gives me a HTMLCollection without the abillity to access "value"-attribute, and anything similar to

```
table.rows[x].getElementsByClassName("product-quantity").getAttribute("value")
```

doesn't work either.

How can I access the value-attribute? I'm new to front-end, so I apologize for potential ignorance with regards to how the HTML DOM works. Thanks everyone/anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
document.querySelector('[id^="product-item-quantity-"]').value
```

It will get the value of the first element with an id that starts with "product-item-quantity-".

You can also use document.querySelectorAll to get an HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Malagasy_aho, with some editing I arrived at the wanted functionality with:

```
var tables;
var table;
var name;
var quantity;

tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
table = tables[1]
name = table.rows[x].querySelector('[class^="modal-link"]').innerHTML
quantity = table.rows[x].querySelector('[id^="product-item-quan]').value
```